# How do you terminate an 'infinite' generator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

EDIT: I edited to include more actual code it seems my 'slimmed down' example was a bit confusing.

I have a javascript array, `questions` of unknown length which contains objects, one for each 'question', each of which has the shape

```
{
  questionID: 1,
  questionText:'bla bla bla',
  end: false
}
```

I also have a function, `getNextQuestion` that takes an `id` and returns a screen

`const getNextQuestion = id => R.find(R.propEq(['questionID'], id))(questions);`

(one could of course use `Array.find` for the above, but I'm exploring Ramda)

I want to write a generator that will yield a particular object from this array, chosen by a passed in `id`, up until an object is yielded which has `end === true`

That is, the object with this particular `id` should be the *last* value returned from the generator.  After that the generator should yield `{value: undefined, done: true`

I thought to write something like this

```
export function* questionGenerator() {
  let nextID = 1;
  let continueLoop = true;
  while (continueLoop) {
    const question = getNextQuestion(nextID);
    if (question.end) continueLoop = false;
    nextID = yield getNextQuestion(nextID);
  }
}
```

which would be called like this

```
const qGen = questionGenerator();
const id = 1;
do {
  const result = gGen.next(i++)
  console.log(result.value)
} while (!result.done)
```

but I'm not sure if that's the best way to write it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: do you have a running example?

Comment: The result of the yield is the value passed into next, I think. This enables bi-directional communication between generator and client. This might help.

Comment: consider break https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: Does `getNextScreen()` really return a screen one time but an id the next time?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the function `getNextScreen`?

Comment: @NinaScholz, not yet, I was working on this at the end of the work day...tomorrow

Comment: @Bergi -- I've edited the code to make it clearer.  But, no, getNextQuestion always returns a 'question' (what I was calling a 'screen' before).  The assignment is part of the generator, where the id is being passed in from outside.

Comment: @trincot -- see above

Comment: @Cerulean Then the `nextID = yield getNextQuestion(nextID);` makes no sense I guess

Comment: @Bergi --The return value of `getNextQuestion` is returned from the generator function with `yield`, that is `yield` _exits_ the function right there before the assignment to `nextID`.  On the next call to `next()`, external to the generator function, the _next_ `nextID` is passed in and assigned to the variable `nextID`.  There is no direct assignment from the right hand side of the statement to the left.   See https://codeburst.io/understanding-generators-in-es6-javascript-with-examples-6728834016d5 -- It's a bit confusing at first that there is no direct assignment, as one would expect.

Comment: @Cerulean Ok, so you really wanted to get the `nextID` from the generator `.next(x)` argument. But you should `yield question`, instead of calling `getNextQuestion` a second time (even if it might work because it's the same argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in the generator to return the generator and another change in the loop for the call of the generator.

```js
const questions = [{ questionID: 1, questionText:'bla bla bla', end: false }, { questionID: 2, questionText:'bla bla bla', end: false }, { questionID: 3, questionText:'bla bla bla', end: false }, { questionID: 4, questionText:'bla bla bla', end: false }, { questionID: 5, questionText:'bla bla bla', end: true }];

const getNextQuestion = (array => id => array.find(({ questionID }) => questionID === id))(questions);

function* questionGenerator() {
    let nextID = 1;
    while (true) {
        const question = getNextQuestion(nextID);
        nextID = yield question;
        if (question.end) return;
    }
}

const gGen = questionGenerator();

var id = 1;

while (true) {
    const result = gGen.next(id++);
    if (result.done) break;
    console.log(result.value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `return` from the generator, which will simplify your code:

```
 while (true) {
  const screen = getNextScreen(nextID);
  nextID = yield screen;
  if (screen.end) return;   
 }
```